# Setting variable in table with docx doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, docx

I'm trying to set a variable in a TableCell inside a TableRow inside a Table which is automatically generated using the docx library (https://github.com/dolanmiu/docx).
Underneath is the code I'm using. First I'm trying to make a table and in the final part I'm using the table to fill a Word Document. In the same document I'm just using  `new Paragraph` to extract the same data from the data property. When using the paragraph my document states a '1', like it should (I'm trying to print variable numbers in my table). In the table nothing shows up, just an empty cell. However when I edit the style in the cell the size of the cell does change according to the new style? Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here and how I should change it? Thanks in advance!

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      budget: {
        planning: 1,
      }
    }
  }
}


const table = new Table({
  rows: [
    new TableRow({
      children: [
        new TableCell({
          children: [new Paragraph(this.budget.planning)],
        }),
        new TableCell({
          children: [new Paragraph(
            text: this.budget.planning,
            heading: heeboNormal //style I defined in my document earlier on
          )],
        }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
})

const doc = new Document({
  sections: [{
    children: [
      table,
      new Paragraph({this.budget.planning})
    ],
  }],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution to the problem. It's probably not the best solution but if someone comes across the same problem, here is a solution. I've only entered the Table code for simplicity.

```
 new Table({
            rows: [
              new TableRow({
                children: [
                  new TableCell({
                    children: [
                      new Paragraph({
                        children: [
                          new TextRun({ text: this.budget.planning }),
                          // Using a TextRun inside the table is the solution 
                          // also make sure to define it as 'text' and it should work!
                        ],
                      }),
                    ],
                  }),
                ],
              }),
            ]
          });
```

Happy Coding!